# Configure prisma to retry connections

Tags: prisma

Is there a way to configure Prisma to retry db connections? I ran into an issue over the weekend where there was instability in my postgres proxy which caused my api layer to fail to serve queries. This instability was transient and ideally I'd like to configure Prisma to retry connecting. Is that possible?

I looked through the [env var reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/environment-variables-reference#proxy-environment-variables), [client api reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference), [schema reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference) and the [database reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference) and didn't see anything which might indicate this feature.

Is it possible to configure prisma to retry connecting to a database when the connection fails?

Comment: Ran into this while responding on a similar GitHub Discussion :)
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/19978

Comment: That was me! Figured I'd cross post since I wasn't sure where I'd be more likely to get a response 

Comment: Nice approach! :)